# What does "Memory Tag 70" mean?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4

The Xcode 4 Allocations profiling instrument may list "Memory Tag 70" as a type under the VM Tracker.  Other types listed are MALLOC_LARGE, MALLOC_SMALL, MALLOC_TINY, "Core Animation", "CG Image", "mapped file", etc.  What type of memory allocation does "Memory Tag 70" stand for?

Comment: Isn't this from the latest beta under NDA?

Comment: The question comes from the released versions of Xcode 4 and iOS 4.

Comment: Ah ok. I came across it watching a WWDC video - but only shortly mentioned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's ImageIO memory, i.e. decoded images that are sticking around.

Comment: Could you please tell us where to learn that, like docs, books?